# JMeter Variables in JSON request

Tags: json, encoding, jmeter, load-testing

When I pass an variable in JMeter HTTP request, I'm getting an exception

> "Unexpected escape character after back slash"

The request body:

```
 "Draft":{
"id": 123654656,
"draftdata":{\\\"accCat\\\":\\\"207\\\",\\\"accNumber\\\":\\\"656565
\\\",\\\"id\\\":${Var_ID},...}
}
```

When I send the request, one of the two back-slashes are omitted. I guess the variable `${Var_ID}` should be passed in a way that does not conflict with the json body

Comment: [tag:dmitri-t] Can you help me please

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think you need these `\\\` signs
2. I believe you need to surround `${Var_ID}` with quotation marks

Something like:

```
{
  "id": 123654656,
  "draftdata": {
    "accCat": "207",
    "accNumber": "656565 ",
    "id": "${Var_ID}"
  }
}
```

You can use online JSON validation tools like [Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to test your JSON payload. Also check out [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for some initial information on testing REST APIs using JMeter

Comment: The problem is that the request body is already encoded and was recorded like this. Is there anyway i can pass variables in encoded requests.
For putting the variable between "" didn't work, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe making changes like:

```
{
   "Draft": {
       "id": 123654656,
       "draftdata": {
           \"accCat\":\"207\",
           \"accNumber\":\"656565\",
           \"id\":\"${Var_ID}\",...}
}
```

I don't see any need to have \ signs, just one will escape original " signs.

Answer (score 0):

The variables, or the request to some function of JMeter, into json body must be passed without quotation marks, something like this:

```
"Draft":{
"id": 123654656,
"draftdata":{
    "accCat":"207",
    "accNumber":"656565",
    "id":${Var_ID},...}
}
```

Also yout don't need the backslashes signs. Hope this help.